# python: всё содержимое из excel файла записать в txt файл

Tags: python-3.x

мучится с поиском значения в excel - надоело!! нужен простой способ всё содержимое excel файла передать txt файлу !!

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Downloads/somefile.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_name(u'лист')
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
```

[image: пример excel и может содержать не только цифры!]

Comment: Как Вы себе это представляете? В первую очередь, я имею в виду перенос столбцов. Также не понятно, что делать с содержимым, которое не имеет строкового представления (не говоря уже о вставках). В общем, приведите, пожалуйста, в вопрос пример документа и результат, который Вы хотите получить. Вы можете это сделать, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Может, для таких целей лучше подойдёт формат `csv`?

Comment: csv пробовал - всё криво как то - записывает по несколько раз в один файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно конвертировать `xlsx` в `csv` (столбцы по умолчанию разделены запятой).

Такая функциональность уже реализована в `pandas` (зависимости: `numpy`, `python-dateutil`, `pytz`, `xlrd`)

***Пример:***

```py
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
f.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: спасибо - попробую в нём строки поискать

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov А чем Вам не нравится прошлый вариант? До сих пор возникает какая-то ошибка?

Comment: да - там кошмар вообще - ошибок море - питон жалуется на содержание excel файла

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov Жаль. Если бы Вы привели файл (или его часть), то было бы легче Вам помочь. Ну а этот вариант Вам подходит? Конвертация завершается без ошибок?

Comment: да спасибо - конвертирует без ошибок - теперь надо с csv бодаться))